# Gameshow: 2-Stages (pick number, then toss a die)

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Pick a number $n \in \{1, \dots, p\}$ (randomly) and toss a fair 6-sided die $n$ times. If you roll at least once the side 6, you win some money. Furthermore if you pick (at random) the number 1 and roll the sides 5 or 6, you win a bike.
>
> (a) What is the probability of picking the number $n$?
>
> (b) What is the probability of winning the money, given that you just picked $n$?
>
> (c) What is the probability of winning the money?
>
> (d) What is the probability of winning anything? (i.e. money or bike)
>
> (e) What is the probability of having picked the number $n$, given that you just won anything?

**EDIT-start**

When i say "pick a number $n \in \{1, \dots, p\}$ (randomly) and toss a fair 6-sided die $n$ times", it has to be viewed as: Image an urn that contains balls with numbers $1$ to $p$ written on them. Pick one of them and assume every ball to be equaly likely to be choosen.

Lets say we pick $1$. Then we are allowed to roll a 6-sided die exactly $1$ time. If we roll $6$ we win some money and a bike. If we roll $5$ we just win the bike, but not the money. If we roll anything else, we get nothing.

Lets say we pick $3$ (and assume $p>=3$). Then we are allowed to roll a 6-sided die exactly $3$ times. If we roll at least once $6$ we win some money. But by definition we can't win the bike, because that's only possible if we had picked the ball $1$ out of the urn.

**EDIT-end**

I have already finished (a)-(d), but think i might have made a mistake along the road, since my answer to (e) just looks wrong.

What i've done so far:

Some notation before we start. Let $A_m$ be the event of tossing the side $m$. Let $B_n$ be the event of picking the number $n$.

(a) Since we pick the number randomly out of $p$ many, the probability is $P(B_n) = \frac{1}{p}$.

(b) It's $P(A_6 | B_n) = (1- (\frac{5}{6})^n)$, since we already know that we picked $n$.

(c) By Bayes we calculate $P(A_6 \cap B_n) = P(A_6 | B_n) \cdot P(B_n) = (1- (\frac{5}{6})^n) \cdot \frac{1}{p}$.

(d) Let $Z := A_6 \cap B_n \cup (A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1$ be the event of winning the money or the bike. We are looking for $P(Z) = P(A_6 \cap B_n) + P((A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1) - P(A_6 \cap B_n \cap (A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1)$. Now

... $P(A_6 \cap B_n) = (1- (\frac{5}{6})^n) \cdot \frac{1}{p}$,

... $P((A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1) = P(A_6 \cup A_5 | B_1) \cdot P(B_1) = \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{p}$,

... $P(A_6 \cap B_n \cap (A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1) \stackrel{?}{=} P(A_6 \cap (A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1) \stackrel{?}{=} P(A_6 \cap B_1) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{p}$.

So $P(Z) = (1- (\frac{5}{6})^n) \cdot \frac{1}{p} + \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{p} = (1- (\frac{5}{6})^n + \frac{1}{6}) \cdot \frac{1}{p}$.

(e) We are looking for $P(B_n | Z) = \frac{P(B_n \cap Z)}{P(Z)} = \frac{P(B_n \cap (A_6 \cap B_n \cup (A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1))}{P(Z)} = \frac{P(B_n \cap A_6 \cap B_n \cup B_n \cap (A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1)}{P(Z)} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{P(A_6 \cap B_n \cup (A_6 \cup A_5) \cap B_1)}{P(Z)} \stackrel{?!}{=} \frac{P(Z)}{P(Z)} = 1$

I'm quite unsure about (d), but (e) is most likely just wrong. Where is my mistake? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your answer for (c) is most probably wrong: the question doesn't refer to $n$, so the answer also shouldn't! The answer should be just a probability expressed in terms of $p$.

The questions (c) and (d) can be answered without using the Bayes theorem, only (e) requires it: $P(B_n | Z) = \frac{P(Z|B_n)P(B_n)}{P(Z)}$. And you just calculated all three needed terms in (b), (a) and (c).

Comment: Also, the whole question is a bit confusing: if you pick 1 in the first stage how can you roll 5 or 6 *at least* once? You are only rolling once in that case, aren't you? You should probably clarify this.

Also, please remove the proof-verification tag, this question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @klao Thanks for the feedback. I just added an example below the question. I can't see how i could solve (c) without using $n$ in the answer, since i just don't know what number got picked in the first stage. What am i missing? Also if you pick 1 in the first stage, you need to roll 5 or 6 to win the bike. "At least once" is wrong in that context, i'll remove it from the question. EDIT: regarding the "proof-verification"-tag: I took "solution-verification", but it keeps changing it to the former :S

Comment: Thanks, the question is completely clear now!

Comment: To solve (c) you have to realize that you can win the money no matter what you picked in the first stage, but of course with different probabilities! And these will all be separate, mutually exclusive ways of winning the money. So $P(M) = \sum_{n=1}^p P(M|B_n) P(B_n)$. Does this help?